# Insert points to a Mongo collection that differ from the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema

I haven't found an answer to what will happen when I try to add points to a Mongo collection that have additional or less fields than the declared schema. Consider the following example using mongoose:

```
var PointSchema = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: [Number]  
  },
  name: String 
})
```

What would happen if I try to insert a document that has only the location field?

And what would happen if I try to insert a document that has all the fields in the schema, but has an additional field not declared in the schema?

I'm also curious to learn wether the answer would be different if I were using just the mongo shell instead of mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you try through a mongoose query using a registered schema
   a. If you insert a single field it will work, because nothing describes either fields as 'required' which you can do if you want to avoid missing fields.
   b. If you insert a field not declared in the schema from node.js you will get a 400 Bad request.
   c. However if you try inserting any number of fields from the mongodb shell, into any given document collection, it would work just fine